# For which values of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ does the matrix have no solutions, one solution and infinite solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

For which values of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ does the matrix have no solutions, one solution and infinite solutions.

I have the following functions: 
$$ax+4y +az=  0 \\
x + ay + 3z = b \\
x(a+1) + y(a+4) + z(a-b^2) = b-2
$$ 
I have reduced this to: 
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1& a& 3 &  b\\
0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2a} & \frac{b}{4-a^2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{b^2+3}
\end{array}\right)
$$
(can't figure out how to make a line in the matrix).

Using this I get to the point where I have $4xb^2+12x-a^2b^2-4a^2 = 8b^3+24b-b^3a^2+3ba^2$ what can I conclude from this, and have I done anything wrong here?

Comment: Division by any expression that contains $a$ or $b$ isn't recommended, as it can be $0$.

Comment: You wrote: *can't figure out how to make a line in the matrix*. I have edited it using array instead of pmatrix. Some basic advice on writing matrices in MathJax can be found [in the tutorial on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First swap the first and second row. Then by subtracting the first and the second row from the third one and then subtracting $a$ times the first row from the second we get:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1& a& 3 &  b\\
0 & 4-a^2 & -2a & -ab \\
0 & 0 & -b^2-3 & -2
\end{array}\right)
$$

If $a \not = \pm 2$ we have a unique solution, as the coefficient matrix would be invertible, considering that $-b^2 - 3 \le -3 < 0$

if $a=\pm2$ by substituting the matrix will reduce to:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1& \pm 2& 3 &  b\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac b2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 + \frac{b^3 + 3b}{2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

The last equation has infinitely many solutions if $-2 + \frac{b^3 + 3b}{2} = 0$ and none otherwise.

Comment: In the third row it must be $-3-b^2$ instead of $-3-b.$

Comment: @mfl I missed the square sign even in my calculations on the paper, so that's what caused me to miss it here. Anyway it shouldn't make much of a difference in method of the solution.

Comment: The method is the same but now you don't have to consider $b=\pm 3.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The system has solution if an only if $$\rm{ran}\begin{pmatrix} a & 4 & a\\ 1 & a & 3 \\ a+1 & a+4& a-b^2\end{pmatrix}=\rm{ran}\begin{pmatrix} a & 4 & a& 0\\ 1 & a & 3 & b\\ a+1 & a+4& a-b^2& b-2\end{pmatrix}.$$ Moreover, it has only a solution if and only if both ranks are $3$ and infinitely many solutions if and only if both ranks are less than $3$ (and equal, of course).

(See Rouché-Capelli theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)

So, we have study the rank of both matrices in terms of $a,b$ and conclude. Note that

$$\rm{ran}\begin{pmatrix} a & 4 & a\\ 1 & a & 3 \\ a+1 & a+4& a-b^2\end{pmatrix}=\rm{ran}\begin{pmatrix} a & 4 & a\\ 1 & a & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -b^2-3\end{pmatrix}.$$ Now

$$\begin{vmatrix} a & 4 & a\\ 1 & a & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -b^2-3\end{vmatrix}=-(b^2+3)(a^2-4).$$ So, if $a\ne \pm 2$ then both ranks are $3$ and the system has only one solution. Study the cases $a=\pm 2.$